# Smarter and easier way to program Telegram bot menus

Tags: node.js, menu, telegram, telegram-bot

I would like to program a Telegram bot in Node.js and Typescript. 
After a start command is received the bot should communicate with single reactive menu - basically something like BotFather's edit bots menu. For the sake of simplicity, the bot should solely handle conversations with a single user(no groups, inline messages and so on).

Here, the term **menu** means a single message with reactive text and buttons. The text is updated according to the user historical choices in the various sub-menus and so are the buttons.

The tedious parts I am trying to get rid of and abstract away are:

1. Encoding each button and each menu identifier in callback_data(callback_data is limited to 64 byte so it even gets worse).
2. Decoding each incoming callback query to figure out which button was pressed in which menu.
3. Manually send the next menu accordingly.

To put it concisely, I want to focus primarily on coding menus and transitions.
Ideally, it should be like programming a static React single page application.

After experimenting several platforms I chose node-telegram-bot-api.
Since I want to build it myself Manybot is not an option.

Checking Google and similar Stackoverflow questions the closest thing I have found is http://github.com/bvn13/TelegramInlineMultipageMenu. Additionally, it doesn't look like any platform mentioned in https://core.telegram.org/bots/samples offers that abstraction.